# Place Hidden input field inside a textarea

Tags: html, input

I am currently working with the wmd text editor. I have been able to fully implement everything without little effort. I am trying to place a hidden field inside a textarea for later use to retrieve the value of the `#wmd-preview` div. The issue is that I am getting the html text attribute of the input field appear inside the actual textarea. I am not sure why is doing so since the attribute of the input is `hidden`.

How can i place a hidden input field inside a textarea then? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/wmd_tester/default.php)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" name="editor-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="6"><input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: you need to put `<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>">` outside of text area. When you write some thing inside a `textarea` then the `textarea` consider it a value of itself.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? May be we can help you .

Comment: @SheikhHeera Thank you, sir. It looks like they answered my question. Overall, I am trying to place a hidden field to later assign it the value of the `wmd-previw` div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything between `<textarea>` tags will be considered text. Why would you want to put it inside the text area in the first place? Why not place it below it? It won't be visible anyway.

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" name="editor-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="6"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>" />
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that happend since it was a hidden field. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you need to put

```
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>">
```

outside of  the `<textarea>`. Because When you write some thing inside a `<textarea>` then the `<textarea>` consider it a value of itself.

You can get the value of hidden text field by placing it outside the `<textarea>` as well.

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" name="editor-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="6"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer**

After fiddling with it for a long time I posted the question here. And by luck I found an answer of how to do it after a few minute of after posted the question. I will not delete the question since I am the FIRST on the internet to find and answer to this question.

For your sake I inputed your code for this example although it can be any code inputed.

This is how I solved the problem by using a hidden textarea linked to the popup javascript. That way what ever is put inside the first textarea will come as a popup and so will also the function from the hidden textarea come on the popup when clicked on the "Preview" button. Test it yourself and you see what I mean.

You can put any HTML or JavaScript code inside the visible textarea wile having all the input field hidden from it but active when the popup is turned on.

**NOTE:** Change the name to editortext deleting "-" from editor-text because the "-" hacks up the JavaScript making it invalid.

**Example using your input code:**

```
<form name = "form1">
<textarea name="textfield" cols="107" rows="31" id="CodeExample" wrap="soft" placeholder="Put your Source Codes here">Try me out</textarea>

<textarea hidden="on" id="wmd-input" name="editortext" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="6">
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" name="myhidden" value="<? $wmdVal ?>">Your hidden input is here delete this text when finished
</textarea>

<br>

<!-- Run Textarea field in popup BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var win = null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll) {
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings =
'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
if (window.focus) {win.focus()}
var t1 = document.form1.textfield.value;
var t2 = document.form1.editortext.value;       
win.document.write(t1);
win.document.write(t2);
}
</script>
<input type = "button" value = "Preview" name = "preview" onclick = "NewWindow('','myPop','500','400','yes')">
<!-- Run Textarea field in popup END -->
</form>
```

**Example using my input code:**

```
<form name = "form1">

<textarea name="textfield" cols="107" rows="31" id="CodeExample" wrap="soft" placeholder="Put your Source Codes here"></textarea>
<textarea hidden="on" name="textfield2" cols="1" rows="1" id="CodeExample2"> </textarea>

<br>

<!-- Run Textarea field in popup BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var win = null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll) {
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings =
'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
if (window.focus) {win.focus()}
var t1 = document.form1.textfield.value;
var t2 = document.form1.textfield2.value;       
win.document.write(t1);
win.document.write(t2);
}
</script>
<input type = "button" value = "Preview" name = "preview" onclick = "NewWindow('','myPop','500','400','yes')">
<!-- Run Textarea field in popup END -->

</form>
```

**NOTE:** As you can see in my example and in also when using your text it work even with HTML and JavaScript codes too.

Comment: I wrote this as a comment though it does not answer the question because by looking at the answers of the other people it is clear they did not understand the question.
So since I have the same problem I clarified the question so now maybe somebody will answer and not give a bad that is equal to not answer at all. 

Anyway thank you I will ask the question since nobody has ever asked this question before.

Comment: After fiddling with it for a long wile I finally found the answer of how to do it. The answer on a question no were to be found on the internet and how many think it is impossible to.
So now this is updated to an answer not a question anymore.
Thank you for your reply and vigilance for the page ;)